# postfix/dovecot: email actually does arrive, but "mail" commands says "no mail" for me (plus from field issue)

Tags: postfix, configuration, dovecot

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a static IP connection.

I have setup `postfix` and `dovecot` to use `Maildir/`.
I can send messages (although, the reply address on recipient's end isn't right) and I **can** and **do** receive emails.  Oddly, however, when I run the `mail` command at my terminal, it says `No mail for jarett`. Everything else is working.  All tests show no errors, anywhere.  DNS is correctly setup, too.  Firewall (both router and computer) are set correctly.  I just cannot figure out why the `mail` doesn't pick it up (when it has in the past, but...configuration and tweaking messed that up)!  I've since ironed out all issues, save for this one.  To be perfectly forward with you, I am not well versed in this subject, so I admit I am having difficulty asking google this question, hence, this post.

I have setup the mailbox type to be ~/Maildir for both postfix and dovecot. Many searches state there should be an environment variable pointing to this folder, but, initially there was not.  Adding "MAIL=~/Maildir/" to .bashrc doesn't do the trick!  So, here is my configuration for both postfix and dovecot:

Contents of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner=$myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff=no
append_dot_mydomain=no
readme_directory=no
compatibility_level=2
home_mailbox = Maildir/

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/night-stand.ca/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/night-stand.ca/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database=btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database=btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_delay_reject=yes
smtpd_helo_required=yes
smtp_always_send_ehlo=yes
smtpd_timeout=30s
smtp_helo_timeout=15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout=15s
smtpd_recipient_limit=40

alias_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/valias
alias_database=hash:/etc/postfix/valias

myhostname=SITE.COM
mydomain=SITE.COM
mydestination=SITE.COM
mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin=$mydomain

relayhost=
mailbox_size_limit=0
recipient_delimiter=+
disable_vrfy_command=yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
minimal_backoff_time=180s
maximal_backoff_time=3h

inet_interfaces=all
inet_protocols=ipv4

invalid_hostname_reject_code=550
non_fqdn_reject_code=550
unknown_address_reject_code=550
unknown_client_reject_code=550
unknown_hostname_reject_code=550
unverified_recipient_reject_code=550
unverified_sender_reject_code=550
```

Contents of `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
}

userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhost/%d/%n
}
```

Oh, perhaps you need to know the hosts file contents and hostname contents
`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  mysiteaddress.tld
```

`/etc/hostname`:

```
www
```

Finally, when I send from the email server to gmail (eg command from terminal: `echo "this is the body" | mail -s "test 1" "myemailaddy@gmail.com"`), gmail says it's coming from "jarett@www" instead of "jarett@mysitesaddress.tld".  What in the world did I do?  Should I change `hostname` to my domain name?

I hope I gave you everything you need, and please don't rake me over the coals if I missed something, or explained it poorly.  I am seeking friendly advice and rather noob with this email server stuff (man, what a rabbit hole).

Sincerly
Jarett

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to read your mail, you need to install [heirloom-mailx](https://askubuntu.com/q/47688/75668). Only this version of the `mail` command supports Maildir format mailboxes.

As for the domain name on outgoing mail, this is caused by Debian's insistence on not following the best practice of naming hosts with their fully qualified domain name. (But don't do this or various Debianisms will probably break). To work around this, set `myorigin=` to your base domain name (e.g. `example.com`, not `www.example.com`) in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast reply. I clicked the install-heirloom-mailx link in the heirloom post you linked to and it installed. I then ran `update-alternatives --config mailx` and selected option `0` (it showed three options, `mailx` being first (auto) and second (manual) and `mail` was the third option).  I ran the `mail` command again, and still no mail.  `mailx` gives same error: `no mail for jarett`.  There are files in both `/home/jarett/Maildir/cur` and `/home/jarett/Maildir/new`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved.  Installed "mutt" (because heirloom failed to achieve results), and modified "myorigin" as Michael suggested (also, aliased mail to mutt for my own memory's sake).  I don't know how to mark this thread as solved.